# Date is showing one day back in another country?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, date, ejs

> I am working with node.js and ejs. I have data in response like

```
[{"message":"","fileSize":"2132","id":"4225","readBy":"2016-03-01 09:04:50","userID":"23","dateTime"
:"2016-03-01 09:03:57","fileName":"movie.mov","fileTicketID":"e0219f64-fb43-4302-8ec3-848a98545048"}
,{"message":"","fileSize":"64132","id":"4226","readBy":"2016-03-01 09:04:50","userID":"23","dateTime"
:"2016-03-01 09:04:20","fileName":"spanish.rtf","fileTicketID":"905f9905-c406-4514-9410-0443c4baa570"
},{"message":"","fileSize":"93430","id":"4227","readBy":"2016-03-01 10:21:07","userID":"23","dateTime"
:"2016-03-01 09:06:08","fileName":"IP estatica.tiff","fileTicketID":"f9bd81a8-b022-4d53-94e7-8301d30ae5e3"
},{"message":"","fileSize":"45","id":"4228","readBy":"2016-03-01 10:21:07","userID":"23","dateTime":"2016-03-01
 09:06:22","fileName":"Text File.txt","fileTicketID":"85a6adb6-15a9-4742-b7d2-05fcd3fa23c1"}]
```

I need to show data date group wise.

I did like below

```
var map = {};

msg1.forEach(function(a){
    var key = a.dateTime.substring(0, 10);
    map[key] = map[key] || [];
    map[key].push(a);
});

Object.keys(map).forEach(function(date){
    var dt = new Date(date),
        monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var dateStr = dt.getDate() + " " + monthNames[dt.getMonth()] + ", " + dt.getFullYear();
    alert(dateStr);
    var el1 = $('<span>' + dateStr + '</span>');
    $(".chat_window ul").append(el1);
    map[date].forEach(function(item){
    //item is the each value in array
    //  alert(item.message);

    var now = item.dateTime;
    var jsDate = toJSDate(now);

    //var dd = jsDate.toLocaleDateString() + " " + jsDate.toLocaleTimeString();
    var msgtime = jsDate.toLocaleTimeString();
    msgtime =  msgtime.replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');
    var el = $('<li class="message right appeared"><div class="avatar"><img src="' + url +
        '/getUserImage/' + item.userID + '/60"/></div><div class="text_wrapper"><div class="text">' +
        item.message + '</div><span>' + msgtime + '</span></div></li>');
});
```

> All things okay in my end it's show date well in my end. But in my
>   clients end it's show the date one day back. As you I already have date
>   in response only  need to format or group data in date wise. So why
>   it's shows one day back. Is this just because of javascript date
>   function?

Comment: In DB how its storing?? one-day back??

Comment: no like above response you can see in db its save "2016-06-22 09:06:22" and when i change it the format then in my end its show 22 june, 2016 but in my client end its shows 20,june 2016. His cuntry is usa

Comment: is there any way to check code with another country in my system

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to **store UTC time in database** and for providing data to client you should set **timezone based on client**'s http call and return time/date accordingly.

Comment: the thing is database is not saved in my end it is save on another party and get response from ther.

Comment: i have doubt here i have date in response just need to format that and group the data like date wise. Is there a way to format the date with another method and group the josn data acouring to the date wise

Comment: Absolutely,  you can change the date in whatever programming language you are using (this needs to be done timezone wise). Then you can group the data based on new dates.

Comment: can you tell me how can i use moment.js with the above response to change the date format

Comment: is there any way to check code with another country in my system.

Comment: Yes you can set a proxy ip for whatever country you want and then check that from browser to simulate exact user/country experience

Comment: can you provide me any environment where i can check my code

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=set+proxy+ip+address+chrome&oq=set+proxy+ip+address+chrome&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5685j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: that is blocked on our end

Comment: can you confirm me one thing moment date format use the system date?

Comment: var date ="2016-06-22"; var Date1 = moment(date, 'YYYY-M-D');
          var dateStr = Date1.format('MMMM D, YYYY'); as date value is coming from json response is its how 22 to all countries?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely running into timezone issues with `toLocaleTimeString`.

Consider using [moment.js timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to force the date to be displayed in X timezone  OR follow @abhinsit advice to store dates in UTC in db and display according to users timezone.

Edit: moment.js example with your data: https://jsfiddle.net/m959mkcr/

Comment: can you tell me how can i use moment.js with the above response to change the date format

Comment: is there any way to check code with another country in my system

Comment: var date ="2016-06-22"; var Date1 = moment(date, 'YYYY-M-D'); var dateStr = Date1.format('MMMM D, YYYY'); as date value is coming from json response is its how 22 to all countries?

Comment: @SumitAggarwal I edited the post with a fiddle to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if it's related to the timezone. The difference might be between your server's timezone and your client's timezone. I would try using something like http://momentjs.com/timezone/ to handle timezones and have the times field on the server stored in the UTC timezone.

Here's example of how to convert June 22 2016 8pm New York time to LA, Europe London time.

```
var newYork    = moment.tz("2016-06-22 20:00", "America/New_York");
var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");

newYork.format();    
losAngeles.format(); 
london.format();
```

Comment: can you tell me how can i use moment.js with the above response to change the date format

Comment: is there any way to check code with another country in my system

Comment: var date ="2016-06-22"; var Date1 = moment(date, 'YYYY-M-D'); var dateStr = Date1.format('MMMM D, YYYY'); as date value is coming from json response is its how 22 to all countries?

Comment: I will add this to my answer